# Custom construction with open generics in StructureMap

Tags: .net, generics, structuremap

I know that for structuremap you can register generic types by specifying the following:

```
StructureMapConfiguration 
   .For(typeof(IRepository<>)) 
   .Use(typeof(RepositoryImplementation<>));
```

When `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Entity>>()` is called the corresponding implementation is returned `RepositoryImplementation<Entity>`.

But what if I want a wrapped version of the repository? A version that also implements `IRepository<Entity>` - lets say `CachedRepository<Entity>` that has a constructor that takes an implementation of `IRepository<TEntity>` ctor: `CachedRepository(IRepository<Entity> innerRepository)`.

How do I get structuremap to return `CachedRepository<Entity>` when asking for an IRepository with the concreate RepositoryImplementation as innerRepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create a custom type interceptor:

```
public class CacheMyRepos : TypeInterceptor
{
    private readonly Type _openTargetType;
    private readonly Type _openWrapperType;

    public CacheMyRepos(Type openTargetType, Type openWrapperType)
    {
        _openTargetType = openTargetType;
        _openWrapperType = openWrapperType;
    }

    public object Process(object target, IContext context)
    {
        var closedWith = target.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var closedWrapperType = _openWrapperType.MakeGenericType(closedWith);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(closedWrapperType, target);
    }

    public bool MatchesType(Type type)
    {
        return type.ImplementsInterfaceTemplate(_openTargetType);
    }
}
```

And then register it with:

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.For(typeof (IRepository<>)).Use(typeof (RepositoryImplementation<>));
    x.RegisterInterceptor(
      new CacheMyRepos(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(CachedRepository<>)));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `CachedRepository<Entity>` have to work with any concrete implementation, or is it safe to tie it to `RepositoryImplementation<Entity>`? If it can be tied, this should do the trick:

```
StructureMapConfiguration
   .For(typeof(IRepository<>)) 
   .Use(typeof(CachedRepository<>));
```

Then change the CachedRepository constructor to `CachedRepository(RepositoryImplementation<Entity> innerRepository)`.

Comment: I would like to keep the interface in the constructor. By doing this I can later add other layers of logic to the repository. I.e CachedRepository -> NotifyingRepository -> LoggingRepository -> TimingRepository -> ActualRepositoryImplementation. By doing this I can keep the logic separated from my actual implementation of repository