# Register Generic Type in StructureMap Based On Concrete Type

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, ninject, structuremap

This is very similar to my [question about Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369425/register-generic-type-in-unity-based-on-concrete-type/24374652), only it applies to StructureMap instead.

I'm trying to emulate a behavior that I can configure in Ninject, only using Unity instead.

I am attempting to use the Cached Repository Pattern, given the following classes and interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Get();
}

public class SqlRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : new()
{
    public T Get()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Getting object of type '{0}'!", typeof(T).Name);
        return new T();
    }
}

public class CachedRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> repository;

    public CachedRepository(IRepository<T> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    private T cachedObject;
    public T Get()
    {
        if (cachedObject == null)
        {
            cachedObject = repository.Get();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Using cached repository to fetch '{0}'!", typeof(T).Name);
        }
        return cachedObject;
    }
}
```

Basically, any time my application uses `IRepository<T>`, it should get an instance of `CachedRepository<T>`. But inside of `CachedRepository<T>` it should fetch the actual SQL repository of `SqlRepository<T>`. In Ninject, I have accomplished this using the following:

```
ninjectModule.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(tyepof(SqlRepository<>)).WhenInjectedExactlyInto(tyepof(CachedRepository<>));
ninjectModule.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(tyepof(CachedRepository<>));
```

In StructureMap, I have accomplished binding to a non-generic repository with the following:

```
x.For<IWidgetRepository>().Use<CachedWidgetRepository>().Ctor<IWidgetRepository>().Is<SqlWidgetRepository>();
```

Unfortunately, the `Ctor` method does not come with an overload that does not take a generic.

```
...Ctor(typeof(IRepository<>))... // Does not exist!
...Ctor<IRepository<>>()... // Compiler error!
```

I *could* register every possible instance manually:

```
x.For<IRepository<Widget>>().Use<CachedRepository<Widget>>().Ctor<IRepository<Widget>>().Is<SqlRepository<Widget>>();
```

but that is obviously not ideal.

EDIT: I found a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079819/custom-construction-with-open-generics-in-structuremap), but the answer appears out of date: StructureMap no longer has a `TypeInterceptor` class to inherit from, but rather exposes an `IInterceptor` interface, so the accepted answer in that StackOverflow question isn't compatible here.

Comment: [This link](http://robtechdiff.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/decorating-generic-interface-with.html) on how to register a decorator may help.

Comment: @Scott I have almost the same issue. Did you ever find a solution for this?